# Importing calendars from MS Exchange

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, calendar, ms-exchange

Outlook / MS Exchange allow to share calendars. For example, in outlook for web access (OWA), I can click on "add calendar" -> "from directory" and then add one of the public calendars for both reading and writing.

Is there a single e-mail client in Linux which would allow this functionality? Not counting using OWA in a browser window? At least for viewing? Note that it is not possible (at least with the versions of MS Exchange / OWA installed by our corpo) to export the calendars as ICS.

I am using Thunderbird, and while it is not a bad client, coupled with MS Exchange it does not perform optimally. I use the commercial ExQuilla plugin for main mail and TbSync for calendar.

I tried Evolution as well, it also does not allow to import other calendars.

Do you have experiences with anything else?